# netMaui Maps confusion

Tags: c#, maui

I am currently highly confused with the netMaui map. I want to set the VisibleRegion of the map programatically and have therefore created a custom map so that i can add some bindable properties for this. In Xamarin Forms i could use the SetVisibleRegion() method. This is where my confusion starts as visual studio tells me that this function does not exist. When i look at the map class, however, we can clearly see that there is such a method existing. The next confusion comes when i look at the source code for the Maui.Controls.Maps.Map i get a class inheriting from IMap when i look at the source of the MoveToRegion() method i get a whole other class. I do not understand how this is happening or how i can now reference the other class? The goal here is that when the user has scrolled from his current position and clicks on the Button in my ViewModel which sets the CustomVisibleRegion property the map resets itself to be centered around the current position.

CustomMap:

```
using Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Maps;
using Microsoft.Maui.Maps;

namespace MauiDoggoApp.Views
{
    public class CustomMap : Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Maps.Map
    {
        // == bindable properties ==
        public MapSpan CurrentLocation
        {
            get
            {
                return (MapSpan)GetValue(CurrentLocationProperty);
            }
            set
            {
                SetValue(CurrentLocationProperty, value);
            }
        }

        public static readonly BindableProperty CurrentLocationProperty = BindableProperty.Create(
            nameof(CurrentLocation),
            typeof(MapSpan),
            typeof(CustomMap),
            defaultBindingMode: BindingMode.TwoWay,
            propertyChanged: CurrentLocationChanged);

        public MapSpan CustomVisibleRegion
        {
            get
            {
                return (MapSpan)GetValue(CustomVisibleRegionProperty);
            }
            set
            {
                SetValue(CustomVisibleRegionProperty, value);
            }
        }
        
        public static readonly BindableProperty CustomVisibleRegionProperty = BindableProperty.Create(
            nameof(CustomVisibleRegion),
            typeof(MapSpan),
            typeof(CustomMap),
            defaultBindingMode: BindingMode.OneWayToSource);

        public CustomMap()
        {
            
        }



        // == override methods ==
        protected override void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName = null)
        {
            base.OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
            if (propertyName == nameof(VisibleRegion))
            {
                CustomVisibleRegion = VisibleRegion;
            }
        }

        // == private methods ==
        private static void CurrentLocationChanged(BindableObject bindable, object oldValue, object newValue)
        {
            Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Maps.Map map = bindable as CustomMap;
            map?.MoveToRegion((MapSpan)newValue);
            map.SetVisibleRegion(newValue);
        }
    }
}
```

With control+ leftclick on Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Maps.Map:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.Maui.Devices.Sensors;
using Microsoft.Maui.Maps;

namespace Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Maps
{
    public partial class Map : IMap, IEnumerable<IMapPin>
    {
        IList<IMapElement> IMap.Elements => _mapElements.Cast<IMapElement>().ToList();

        IList<IMapPin> IMap.Pins => _pins.Cast<IMapPin>().ToList();

        void IMap.Clicked(Location location) => MapClicked?.Invoke(this, new MapClickedEventArgs(location));

        MapSpan? IMap.VisibleRegion
        {
            get
            {
                return _visibleRegion;
            }
            set
            {
                SetVisibleRegion(value);
            }

        }

        protected override void OnHandlerChanged()
        {
            base.OnHandlerChanged();
            //The user specified on the ctor a MapSpan we now need the handler to move to that region
            Handler?.Invoke(nameof(IMap.MoveToRegion), _lastMoveToRegion);
        }

    }
}
```

With left click on MoveToRegion():

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Collections.Specialized;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Internals;
using Microsoft.Maui.Maps;

namespace Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Maps
{
    public partial class Map : View
    {
        public static readonly BindableProperty MapTypeProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(MapType), typeof(MapType), typeof(Map), default(MapType));

        public static readonly BindableProperty IsShowingUserProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(IsShowingUser), typeof(bool), typeof(Map), default(bool));

        public static readonly BindableProperty IsTrafficEnabledProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(IsTrafficEnabled), typeof(bool), typeof(Map), default(bool));

        public static readonly BindableProperty IsScrollEnabledProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(IsScrollEnabled), typeof(bool), typeof(Map), true);

        public static readonly BindableProperty IsZoomEnabledProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(IsZoomEnabled), typeof(bool), typeof(Map), true);

        public static readonly BindableProperty ItemsSourceProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(ItemsSource), typeof(IEnumerable), typeof(Map), default(IEnumerable),
            propertyChanged: (b, o, n) => ((Map)b).OnItemsSourcePropertyChanged((IEnumerable)o, (IEnumerable)n));

        public static readonly BindableProperty ItemTemplateProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(ItemTemplate), typeof(DataTemplate), typeof(Map), default(DataTemplate),
            propertyChanged: (b, o, n) => ((Map)b).OnItemTemplatePropertyChanged((DataTemplate)o, (DataTemplate)n));

        public static readonly BindableProperty ItemTemplateSelectorProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(ItemTemplateSelector), typeof(DataTemplateSelector), typeof(Map), default(DataTemplateSelector),
            propertyChanged: (b, o, n) => ((Map)b).OnItemTemplateSelectorPropertyChanged());

        readonly ObservableCollection<Pin> _pins = new();
        readonly ObservableCollection<MapElement> _mapElements = new();
        MapSpan? _visibleRegion;
        MapSpan? _lastMoveToRegion;

        public Map(MapSpan region)
        {
            MoveToRegion(region);
#pragma warning disable CS0618 // Type or member is obsolete
            VerticalOptions = HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand;
#pragma warning restore CS0618 // Type or member is obsolete

            _pins.CollectionChanged += PinsOnCollectionChanged;
            _mapElements.CollectionChanged += MapElementsCollectionChanged;
        }


        // center on Maui by default
        public Map() : this(new MapSpan(new Devices.Sensors.Location(20.793062527, -156.336394697), 0.5, 0.5))
        {
        }

        public bool IsScrollEnabled
        {
            get { return (bool)GetValue(IsScrollEnabledProperty); }
            set { SetValue(IsScrollEnabledProperty, value); }
        }

        public bool IsZoomEnabled
        {
            get { return (bool)GetValue(IsZoomEnabledProperty); }
            set { SetValue(IsZoomEnabledProperty, value); }
        }

        public bool IsShowingUser
        {
            get { return (bool)GetValue(IsShowingUserProperty); }
            set { SetValue(IsShowingUserProperty, value); }
        }

        public bool IsTrafficEnabled
        {
            get => (bool)GetValue(IsTrafficEnabledProperty);
            set => SetValue(IsTrafficEnabledProperty, value);
        }

        public MapType MapType
        {
            get { return (MapType)GetValue(MapTypeProperty); }
            set { SetValue(MapTypeProperty, value); }
        }

        public IList<Pin> Pins
        {
            get { return _pins; }
        }

        public IEnumerable ItemsSource
        {
            get { return (IEnumerable)GetValue(ItemsSourceProperty); }
            set { SetValue(ItemsSourceProperty, value); }
        }

        public DataTemplate ItemTemplate
        {
            get { return (DataTemplate)GetValue(ItemTemplateProperty); }
            set { SetValue(ItemTemplateProperty, value); }
        }

        public DataTemplateSelector ItemTemplateSelector
        {
            get { return (DataTemplateSelector)GetValue(ItemTemplateSelectorProperty); }
            set { SetValue(ItemTemplateSelectorProperty, value); }
        }

        public IList<MapElement> MapElements => _mapElements;

        public event EventHandler<MapClickedEventArgs>? MapClicked;

        public MapSpan? VisibleRegion
        {
            get { return _visibleRegion; }
        }

        public IEnumerator<IMapPin> GetEnumerator()
        {
            return _pins.GetEnumerator();
        }

        public void MoveToRegion(MapSpan mapSpan)
        {
            if (mapSpan == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(mapSpan));
            _lastMoveToRegion = mapSpan;
            Handler?.Invoke(nameof(IMap.MoveToRegion), _lastMoveToRegion);
        }

        IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
        {
            return GetEnumerator();
        }

        void SetVisibleRegion(MapSpan? visibleRegion)
        {
            if (visibleRegion == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(visibleRegion));

            if (_visibleRegion == visibleRegion)
                return;

            OnPropertyChanging(nameof(VisibleRegion));
            _visibleRegion = visibleRegion;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(VisibleRegion));
        }

        void PinsOnCollectionChanged(object? sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.NewItems != null && e.NewItems.Cast<Pin>().Any(pin => pin.Label == null))
                throw new ArgumentException("Pin must have a Label to be added to a map");
            Handler?.UpdateValue(nameof(IMap.Pins));
        }

        void MapElementsCollectionChanged(object? sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            Handler?.UpdateValue(nameof(IMap.Elements));
            if (e.NewItems != null)
            {
                foreach (MapElement item in e.NewItems)
                {
                    item.PropertyChanged += MapElementPropertyChanged;
                }
            }

            if (e.OldItems != null)
            {
                foreach (MapElement item in e.OldItems)
                {
                    item.PropertyChanged -= MapElementPropertyChanged;
                }
            }
        }

        void MapElementPropertyChanged(object? sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (sender is MapElement mapElement)
            {
                var index = MapElements.IndexOf(mapElement);
                var args = new Maui.Maps.Handlers.MapElementHandlerUpdate(index, mapElement);
                Handler?.Invoke(nameof(Maui.Maps.Handlers.IMapHandler.UpdateMapElement), args);
            }
        }

        void OnItemsSourcePropertyChanged(IEnumerable oldItemsSource, IEnumerable newItemsSource)
        {
            if (oldItemsSource is INotifyCollectionChanged ncc)
            {
                ncc.CollectionChanged -= OnItemsSourceCollectionChanged;
            }

            if (newItemsSource is INotifyCollectionChanged ncc1)
            {
                ncc1.CollectionChanged += OnItemsSourceCollectionChanged;
            }

            _pins.Clear();
            CreatePinItems();
        }

        void OnItemTemplatePropertyChanged(DataTemplate oldItemTemplate, DataTemplate newItemTemplate)
        {
            if (newItemTemplate is DataTemplateSelector)
            {
                throw new NotSupportedException(
                    $"The {nameof(Map)}.{ItemTemplateProperty.PropertyName} property only supports {nameof(DataTemplate)}." +
                    $" Set the {nameof(Map)}.{ItemTemplateSelectorProperty.PropertyName} property instead to use a {nameof(DataTemplateSelector)}");
            }

            _pins.Clear();
            CreatePinItems();
        }

        void OnItemTemplateSelectorPropertyChanged()
        {
            _pins.Clear();
            CreatePinItems();
        }

        void OnItemsSourceCollectionChanged(object? sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            e.Apply(
                insert: (item, _, __) => CreatePin(item),
                removeAt: (item, _) => RemovePin(item),
                reset: () => _pins.Clear());
            Handler?.UpdateValue(nameof(IMap.Pins));
        }

        void CreatePinItems()
        {
            if (ItemsSource == null || (ItemTemplate == null && ItemTemplateSelector == null))
            {
                return;
            }

            foreach (object item in ItemsSource)
            {
                CreatePin(item);
            }

            Handler?.UpdateValue(nameof(IMap.Pins));
        }

        void CreatePin(object newItem)
        {
            DataTemplate? itemTemplate = ItemTemplate;
            if (itemTemplate == null)
                itemTemplate = ItemTemplateSelector?.SelectTemplate(newItem, this);

            if (itemTemplate == null)
                return;

            var pin = (Pin)itemTemplate.CreateContent();
            pin.BindingContext = newItem;
            _pins.Add(pin);
        }

        void RemovePin(object itemToRemove)
        {
            //// Instead of just removing by item (i.e. _pins.Remove(pinToRemove))
            ////  we need to remove by index because of how Pin.Equals() works
            for (int i = 0; i < _pins.Count; ++i)
            {
                Pin? pin = _pins[i] as Pin;
                if (pin != null)
                {
                    if (pin.BindingContext?.Equals(itemToRemove) == true)
                    {
                        _pins.RemoveAt(i);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I mean even when they are partial why cannot i set the Visible Region in any case? What i also do not understand is when i let the map in the CurrentLocationChanged() method be of type IMap i can set the visible region, however, the map only focuses on this position if i set a breakpoint at this stage!?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you're having issues - this code works fine for me

```
protected override void OnAppearing()
    {
        base.OnAppearing();

        MapSpan span = new MapSpan(new Location(29.76, -95.36), 1, 1);

        map.MoveToRegion(span);
    }
```

Comment: My Problem is when the Map is set to my position and  I manually scrolling on the map and then want to recenter it what do I use now? In Xamarin Forms I used the SetVisibleRegion method but this is not public anymore.

Comment: use `MoveToRegion` as shown in my example